# Oracle Group By Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am strugling with what seems an easy problem to tackle (at least for me in MySQL / SqlServer!)

I'll simplify the problem. Let's say I have the following table:

Table VOTE

```
ID  ID_IDEA DATE_VOTE   with ID_IDEA FK(IDEA.ID)
1   3       10/10/10
2   0       09/09/10
3   3       08/08/10
4   3       11/11/10
5   0       06/06/10
6   1       05/05/10
```

I'm trying to find the latest votes given for each individual idea, meaning I want to return only rows with ID 4, 2 and 6.

It seems with Oracle that you can't use GROUP BY without using a function like SUM(), AVG, etc. I'm a bit confused about how it's supposed to work.

Please advise,

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       id_idea,
       date_vote
FROM   (SELECT id,
               id_idea,
               date_vote,
               Row_number() over (PARTITION BY id_idea 
                                      ORDER BY date_vote DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
        FROM   VOTE) AS t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Generally when ORDERing DESC it is a good idea to force NULLs to be LAST, so you are more likely to pick up a row that has real data.

Comment: @EvilTeach My guess would be that this is unlikely to be nullable but point taken and edit made.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are looking for this:

```
SELECT id_idea, max(date_vote)
FROM vote
GROUP BY id_idea
```

Edit: on second thought if you need to get the full row:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM vote v
  JOIN (SELECT id_idea, max(date_vote) as max_date
        FROM vote
        GROUP BY id_idea) t
    ON t.id_idea = v.id_idea AND t.max_date = v.date_vote
```

Comment: They want `id` as well I think. A greatest n per group query.

Comment: With the first or the second query? Did you change anything with my query?

Comment: yea i had to change it to fit my context which is more complex. But the inner query won't accept the group by when run on the side

Comment: You will need to show the modified query, otherwise we will not be able to tell the reason for the error. What do you mean with "run on the side"?

Answer (score 1):

You should not handle such a query with analytic functions, if you can do it by simply aggregating:

```
SQL> create table vote(id,id_idea,date_vote)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 3, date '2010-10-10' from dual union all
  4  select 2, 0, date '2010-09-09' from dual union all
  5  select 3, 3, date '2010-08-08' from dual union all
  6  select 4, 3, date '2010-11-11' from dual union all
  7  select 5, 0, date '2010-06-06' from dual union all
  8  select 6, 1, date '2010-05-05' from dual
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by date_vote) id
  2       , id_idea
  3       , max(date_vote) date_vote
  4    from vote
  5   group by id_idea
  6  /

        ID    ID_IDEA DATE_VOTE
---------- ---------- -------------------
         2          0 09-09-2010 00:00:00
         6          1 05-05-2010 00:00:00
         4          3 11-11-2010 00:00:00

3 rows selected.
```

Compared to the analytic variant:

1) it works (ok the analytic one also works if you remove 'AS' in 'AS t')

2) it is shorter

3) it is clearer (ok, that's subjective)

4) it is a tiny bit more performant, see:

This is the plan for the aggregation query:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2103353780

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     3 |    39 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |      |     3 |    39 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| VOTE |     6 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is the plan for the analytic query:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 781916126

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |      |     6 |   288 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |      |     6 |   288 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|      |     6 |    78 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | VOTE |     6 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RN"=1)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY "ID_IDEA" ORDER BY
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("DATE_VOTE") DESC  NULLS LAST)<=1)
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thanks for your deep answer Rob. We actually ended up doing something quite like this just before reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally do this using the [first or last function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm#i1000901). It has a bit of a strange construction which might explain why it doesn't get used very often. Note that, as long as the order by clause is deterministic then the max/min in't important (but is needed because that is the way the function is constructed.

```
select 
  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by date_vote) as id,
  id_idea,
  max(date_vote)
  from vote
group by id_idea
```